# The appendTo() function in js didn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web

I met a problem with js. The js function appendTo() is not work!
my js code is like this:
[image]

my browser console shows that everythings is as planed:
[image]

here is the problem , my html element tbody doesn't contain any things as followed:
[image]

why? how can i fix this?

Comment: have you try to hardcode and see the result? $('#tb_10.3.3.186:3222').append('test');

Comment: @DennySutedja yes, i have try, didn't work either, same problem

Comment: `$('#tb_' + serverList[i]).append(html)` and not `($('#tb_' + serverList[i])).append(html)`

Comment: you get this <tbody> from looping ?? or from ajax??

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri ok, but still not work. Thanks, the problem is solved by elfan's answer

Comment: @DennySutedja from ajax , but i had set async as false. Thanks, the problem is solved by elfan's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although HTML id is allowed to contain dot and colon characters, the fact that you are using jQuery makes it doesn't work because dot and colon have special meaning in a a selector context.

The following native JS will work:

```
document.getElementById('tb_10.3.3.186:32222').innerHTML += html;
```

But if you still want to use jQuery, you need to remove the dot (`.`) and colon (`:`) from your `id`.